# Symfony2: JSON Response To Twig?

Tags: json, mongodb, symfony, twig

i'm getting a json response from mongodb, but i can't get this into a twig template. could somebody explain it and show best pratice? thanks.

```
/**
 * @Route("/event/{id}", name="event_details_view")
 * @Template()
 */
public function viewAction($id)
{
    $event = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')
        ->getRepository('DungeonEventBundle:Event')
        ->findById($id);

    if (!$event) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Event .$id. was not found.');
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($event));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not getting a JSON response from MongoDB — you are getting an `Event` document object. If you want to pass it to Twig, instead of returning a response, return an array (since you're using the `@Template` annotation:

```
return array('event' => $event);
```

The object will be accessible in your template as `event`.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. if i return the event document as an array to the twig template i'm getting an error: `Method "eventTitle" for object "Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\LoggableCursor" does not exist in DungeonEventBundle:Event:view.html.twig at line 4`. what's wrong here? :/

Comment: The problem is that `$event` is not a single document, but a collection of documents. Use `find()` (or `findOneById()`) instead of `findById()`.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice describe here would be to use a `base.json.twig` template, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146460/symfony2-echoing-json-from-a-controller-for-use-in-an-extjs-4-grid) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617495/symfony2-twig-json-templates-vs-json-encode-whats-right-for-this-situation), instead  of `Response(json_encode($data))`.