# Symfony2: Echoing JSON From a Controller for Use in an ExtJS 4 Grid

Tags: php, json, model-view-controller, symfony, extjs4

I'm just getting started with Symfony2 and I'm trying to figure out what the correct approach is for echoing out JSON from a controller (e.g., `People`) for use in an ExtJS 4 grid.

When I was doing everything using a vanilla MVC approach, my controller would have method called something like `getList` that would call the `People` model's `getList` method, take those results and do something like this:

```
<?php
class PeopleController extends controller {
    public function getList() {
        $model = new People();
        $data = $model->getList();
        echo json_encode(array(
            'success' => true,
            'root' => 'people',
            'rows' => $data['rows'],
            'count' => $data['count']
        ));
    }
}
?>
```

- What does this kind of behavior look like in Symfony2?
- Is the controller the right place for this kind of behavior?
- What are the best practices (within Symfony) for solving this kind of problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is the controller the right place for this kind of behavior?

Yes.

> What does this kind of behavior look like in Symfony2?
>
> What are the best practices (within Symfony) for solving this kind of problem?

In symfony it looks pretty much alike, but there are couple of nuances.

I want to suggest my approach for this stuff. Let's start from routing:

```
# src/Scope/YourBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

ScopeYourBundle_people_list:
    pattern:  /people
    defaults: { _controller: ScopeYourBundle:People:list, _format: json }
```

The `_format` parameter is not required but you will see later why it's important.

Now let's take a look at controller

```
<?php
// src/Scope/YourBundle/Controller/PeopleController.php
namespace Overseer\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller; 

class PeopleController extends Controller
{   
  public function listAction()
  {
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    // if ajax only is going to be used uncomment next lines
    //if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest())
      //throw $this->createNotFoundException('The page is not found');

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
          ->getRepository('ScopeYourBundle:People');

    // now you have to retrieve data from people repository.
    // If the following code looks unfamiliar read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html
    $items = $repository->findAll();
    // or you can use something more sophisticated:
    $items = $repository->findPage($request->query->get('page'), $request->query->get('limit'));
    // the line above would work provided you have created "findPage" function in your repository

    // yes, here we are retrieving "_format" from routing. In our case it's json
    $format = $request->getRequestFormat();

    return $this->render('::base.'.$format.'.twig', array('data' => array(
      'success' => true,
      'rows' => $items,
      // and so on
    )));
  }
  // ...
}
```

Controller renders data in the format which is set in the routing config. In our case it's the json format.

Here is example of possible template:

```
{# app/Resourses/views/base.json.twig #}
{{ data | json_encode | raw }}
```

The advantage of this approach (I mean using _format) is that it if you decide to switch from json to, for example, xml than no problem - just replace _format in routing config and, of course, create corresponding template.

Comment: Actually I did. See the last code block `{{ data | json_encode | raw }}`

Answer (score 8):

I would avoid using a template to render the data as the responsibility for escaping data etc is then in the template.   Instead I use the inbuilt json_encode function in PHP much as you have suggested.

Set the route to the controller in the routing.yml as suggested in the previous answer:

```
ScopeYourBundle_people_list:
pattern:  /people
defaults: { _controller: ScopeYourBundle:People:list, _format: json }
```

The only additional step is to force the encoding in the response.

```
<?php
class PeopleController extends controller {
    public function listAction() {
        $model = new People();
        $data = $model->getList();
        $data = array(
            'success' => true,
            'root' => 'people',
            'rows' => $data['rows'],
            'count' => $data['count']
        );
        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(json_encode($data));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just a small side note, if the route specify the `_format` option correctly, the `Content-Type` header is set automatically by Symfony2 as it can be seen in the `Response` class [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php#L166). Since, in this example, the format is `json`, the `Content-Type` header with value `'application/json'` will be appended to the response.

Answer (score 1):

To use `return new JsonResponse(array('a' => 'value', 'b' => 'another-value');` you need to use the right namespace:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
```

As described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building your own response you can also use the built-in *JsonResponse*.

You define the route like in the other answers suggested:

```
ScopeYourBundle_people_list:
pattern:  /people
defaults: { _controller: ScopeYourBundle:People:list, _format: json }
```

And use the new response type:

```
<?php
class PeopleController extends controller {
    public function listAction() {
        $model = new People();
        $data = $model->getList();
        $data = array(
            'success' => true,
            'root' => 'people',
            'rows' => $data['rows'],
            'count' => $data['count']
        );
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($data);
    }
}
```

For more information see the [api](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html) or the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#creating-a-json-response) (version 2.6).

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Use [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) and only return the People object from the controller.

Answer (score -2):

use

```
    return JsonResponse($data, StatusCode, Headers);
```