# $_GET in symfony2 to get many variables

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get the variables from a $_GET request 
the request is like /markers/var1/var2/var3/var4
the route file is as follows:

```
Markers:
pattern:  /markers/{slug}
defaults: { _controller: ngNearBundle:Markers:index }
```

First question is :

1. does index method need to be an action method ? "indexAction" the method will output json.
2. how can I get the value of var1 and var2 etc ... ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
Yes it needs to be an action inside of a controller. If you return a `JSON` body you can use the [JsonResponse](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#component-http-foundation-json-response).

2)
You just need to change the pattern of your `action`

```
Markers:
    pattern: /markers/{slug}/{var2}/{var3}/{var4}
    defaults: { _controller: ngNearBundle:Markers:index }
```

And in your `MarkersController` you add an action like this:

```
public function indexAction($slug, $var2, $var3, $var4) {
    //...
}
```

Alternatively you can leave your route like this: `/markers/{slug}`, add the other variables as plain `GET` variables (`/markers/test?var2=a&var3=b&var4=c`) and access them in your `action` like this:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request, $slug) {
    $var2 = $request->query->get('var2');
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! for Json I found this topic , not the top answer but the second one is great ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146460/symfony2-echoing-json-from-a-controller-for-use-in-an-extjs-4-grid